# Configuring sentry before_send hook on data-composer

Tags: sentry, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to configure before_send hook in sentry section of airflow configuration overrides.
My before_send function is in `plugins/sentry/sentry_setup.py`, function is called `before_send`

My question is what value should I use for the sentry.before_send field ? I am using `plugins.sentry.sentry_setup.before_send` but when updating the environment, the process fails with an error `"No module named 'sentry'"`

I tried configuring the value to sentry.sentry_setup.before_send with the same result.

How do I configure this , where do I have to place my before_send function definition ?